# Pass variable from view to jquery ajax that load another view in code igniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having a great trouble passing the variable from a view. 
This code is a profile thread that has three sections: overview, comments, and threads. To move to another section, I'm using ajax.

The controller to profile page

```
public function profile($id){
    $this->data['posts']=$this->HomeModel->getProfileData($id);

    $this->load->view('forum-profile.php',$this->data);
}
```

The HomeModel

```
public function getProfileData($id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
    $query=$this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

This is the button to each section

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item p-menu active" id="overview">Status</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item p-menu" id="komentar">Komentar</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item p-menu" id="thread">Judul Topik</a>
```

And this is the jquery

```
$('#overview').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL+'/FPpweb/page/stats', 
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response){
         $('.profile-body').html(response);
        }
    });
});

$('#komentar').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL+'/FPpweb/page/komen',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response){
         $('.profile-body').html(response);
        }
    });
});

$('#thread').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL+'/FPpweb/page/trit',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response){
         $('.profile-body').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: forgot each sections controller

```
public function stats(){ 
    $this->load->view('profile-overview.php');
}

public function komen(){
    $this->load->view('profile-komentar.php');
}

public function trit(){
    $this->load->view('profile-thread.php');
}
```

The url will be something like `http://localhost/FPpweb/page/profile/17`
How can I pass the `user_id` to my other sections using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have user id available in your view. you can use data: { name: yourValue } to send data.

```
$('#overview').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: BASE_URL+'/FPpweb/page/stats', 
    type: 'POST',
    data: { userId: user_id },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response){
     $('.profile-body').html(response);
    }
});
```

});

data

Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I have this variable '$post->user_id' . 
And when I use 'data: { userId: user_id },' I get message "userId not defined"

Comment: I used the 'data: { userId: user_id },' , but how can I acces the userId on the new view?

Comment: Ajax will post data and it will be available in form collection.I do not know php. but  it should be possible to do something like Request.Form("userid").